# Using Top 1 in SQL instead of Looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I have the following vba code that I am converting to SQL...

```
      Do While Not sRst1.EOF
            sRst1.MoveLast
            sRst1.MoveFirst

            If (sRst1!Field1 = "FileName") Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            sCtr = sCtr + 1
            sRst1.MoveNext
      Loop
```

So basically I need to grab the first record where field1 is equal to FileName, which I could probably do by selecting TOP(1) where field1 = "FileName" if I'm not mistaken? Also, I need to return a count of how many records it took to get to that record. How could I do that?

Comment: To count the number of rows you need until finding the first matching will depend on the order in which you traverse the rows. And SQL does not guarantee any specific order if you do not explicitly set one. In which order do you want to traverse the rows?

Comment: There actually was never an order specified in the original application, the recordset was opened in a temp table and then the cursor was move to the first record.

Comment: So you were just lucky if you got the same number using this method in several calls. Or maybe the cursor used an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Well the ctr handles the luck part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) row_num FROM sRst1) 
SELECT field1,row_num FROM t WHERE field1 = 'FileName'
```

As FrankPl points out, row_num will be effectively random if you don't tell SQL what order you want.  Replace "(SELECT 0)" with "field1" or some other column to fix this.

Comment: There must be a native order in MS Access when data is inserted into a table, if not, then I guess I'll just leave the order by out, the application wasn't designed by me so I can't say as to what they were looking to do exactly.

Comment: SQL Server != MS Access